# Android Studio 1.5.1.Rendering error (Floating action button)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a brand new developer in the android world (so with that in mind please forgive me if this question is dumb) and I just started a new project. The API I am using is 16 (4.1) and I started my project using a blank activity and the Main_Activity and I got the following rendering problem 'The following classes could not be instantiated: -android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton'I have tried building and rebuilding my project but the error is not going away. In your response please use very simple terms as I am very new developer. Thanks!

Comment: This is a brand new project that you have not modified in any way?

Comment: Nope aside from naming it and choosing blank activity

Comment: try File->Invalidate Cache and Restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the design support library in your Gradle dependencies? Maybe you need to add these

```
 dependencies{
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
 }
```

Comment: I did have the desing support library in my dependencies  except that mine were of version v7:23.2.0 so I rolled them back to 23.1.1 then I restarted and rebuilt and it worked voila! Thanks so much!